# Convention Questions for Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing, discrete-time

When describing the matrix form for the change of basis, my book says that the matrix you construct from the basis vectors is by taking the complex conjugate of each basis vector and turning that into a row. Then to get the new coordinates you just do 
$$ M\vec{x}=\vec{y}$$

I seem to recall in previous classes that you construct a matrix where each column is a basis vector and then do
$$ M^H \vec{x} = \vec{y}$$

Is the first or second more typical in convention. Is the convention different for discrete signal processing than for just math?

Comment: There is no common convention here. Use whichever is more convenient for your application. The only difference between the two is that the letter $M$ represents a different matrix itself in the first than in the second. By the description of how $M$ is built in each, it should be obvious that the $M$ of the first is indeed the same as $M^{H}$ for the second.